# suitable normalization method for clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, normalization, data-mining

my task is to first calculate the distance matrix from the data, and then use distance matrix as the input of clustering algorithms. I need to normalize the distance matrix into 0~1 before use it, but have problem with choosing a suitable method. As far as I know, both Z-score and Min-Max are two popular approach for normalization, which one would you suggest for a clustering task?

Comment: This question seems quite open. I would suggest you change the way of asking to be little bit constrained, like what the pro/cons to subjective methods, is there any else method can meet your specific need.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainty do some kind of feature scaling on your data.

```
# Normalization

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df
y = target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=27)

# data normalization with sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# fit scaler on training data
norm = MinMaxScaler().fit(X_train)

# transform training data
X_train_norm = norm.transform(X_train)

# transform testing dataabs
X_test_norm = norm.transform(X_test)
```

Or...

```
# data standardization with  sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# copy of datasets
X_train_stand = X_train.copy()
X_test_stand = X_test.copy()

# numerical features
num_cols = ['Item_Weight','Item_Visibility','Item_MRP','Outlet_Establishment_Year']

# apply standardization on numerical features
for i in num_cols:
    
    # fit on training data column
    scale = StandardScaler().fit(X_train_stand[[i]])
    
    # transform the training data column
    X_train_stand[i] = scale.transform(X_train_stand[[i]])
    
    # transform the testing data column
    X_test_stand[i] = scale.transform(X_test_stand[[i]])
```

Refer to the link below for more info.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/feature-scaling-machine-learning-normalization-standardization/